# Error al entrar a Mysql con XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

al  intentar ingresar al servidor de phpmyadmin en mi local host me manda este error,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] mi código original es este en mi config.inc.php

```
   `/* Authentication type and info */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
   $cfg['Lang'] = '';`
```

Vi otros comentarios donde dicen que se resuelve cambiando la contraseña , pero en mi caso no fue así, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Buenas tardes a lo mejor esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341504/how-to-configure-config-inc-php-to-have-a-loginform-in-phpmyadmin) del SO te puede ayudar

Answer (score 1):

> Vi otros comentarios donde dicen que se resuelve cambiando la contraseña , pero en mi caso no fue así, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Has revisado que el servicio de MySQL este activo en el panel de control de XAMPP?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo también mi configuración completa del archivo config.inc.php por si has cambiado algún valor en algún lugar haciendo pruebas.

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

Comment: Gracias xc , pero si si tenia activado el servicio de MySQL  lo que me ayudo es agregar " skip-grant-tables" en el archivo de my.ini antes del puerto.